# looking for a way to build nice animation ReactJS carousel without Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, carousel

I got my ReactJS code here sirs. It was a simple one with inline  carousel. I really want to build one nice carousel without the help of Bootstrap. I want to put some slow sliding animation between the images i couldnt.

Here is my recent code. Many thanks for stoop by and take a look sirs.

```
       `class LoadIMG extends Component{
         constructor(props){
         super(props);
         this.state = {
         number : 1
         }
          }
          prev(){
          this.setState({
         number : this.state.number == 1 ? 1: this.state.number - 1
         })
         }
         next(){
         this.setState({
         number : this.state.number == 4 ? 4: this.state.number + 1
         })
         }
         render(){
         return(
         <div>
        <img src={"images/" + this.state.number + ".jpg"}/>
        <button onClick={this.prev.bind(this)} className="button"> 
        Prev</button>
        <button onClick={this.next.bind(this)} className="button"> 
        Next</button>
       </div>
        )
         }
       }
        export default LoadIMG;`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add a question about a concrete problem you are struggeling with.

Comment: You should take a look at [react-transition-group](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group). If you want it to be even more advanced you could use [react-motion](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion).

Comment: thankiu sir u best the